# Row counts in a cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to get the row counts in a cursor I have used `cursor_name%rowcount` but this returns always `0`?

Comment: A cursor is not an array. It has no data. `ROWCOUNT` can only tell you how many rows you have already fetched from the cursor. See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems011.htm#:~:text=%25ROWCOUNT%20Attribute,of%20rows%20fetched%20so%20far.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to fetch it first.
Example:

```
DECLARE
     CURSOR cursor_name IS
            SELECT * FROM table_name;
     tmp    cursor_name%ROWTYPE;
     v_cnt  NUMBER;
BEGIN
     OPEN cursor_name;
     LOOP
          FETCH cursor_name
          INTO tmp;
          EXIT WHEN cursor_name%NOTFOUND;
     END LOOP;
     v_cnt := cursor_name%ROWCOUNT;
     CLOSE cursor_name;
END;
/
```

Regarding to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems011.htm):

> **%ROWCOUNT Attribute:** A cursor attribute that can be appended to the name of a cursor or
> cursor variable. When a cursor is opened, %ROWCOUNT is zeroed. Before
> the first fetch, cursor_name%ROWCOUNT returns 0. Thereafter, it
> returns the number of rows fetched so far. The number is incremented
> if the latest fetch returned a row.